# AnyHashable dictionary conversion, changes a key value(is also a Dictionary) of the result dictionary into a String instead of Dictionary

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary, apple-push-notifications, hashable

This is the result dictionary getting when I converted the `Dictionary<AnyHashable, Any>` to `Dictionary<String, Any>`,

```
{
    "payload":"{\"type_nm\":\"Test\",\"crcd_dt\":{\"date\":\"2020-06-03T09:44:27.211Z\"},\"read\":false,\"crdt_by\":1001,\"org_id\":50581,\"ent_no\":30599}",
    "message":"Push Notification",
    "google.c.sender.id":"1234567890",
    "timestamp":"1591177467211",
    "title":"Test1",
    "aps":{
             "alert":{
                "title":"App Push Notification",
                "body":"Testing the push notification feature"
             },
             "sound":"default",
             "mutable-content":"1"
          }
    },
    "gym.message_id":"9876543210",
    "is_background":"false"
 }
```

The problem here is, the value of `payload` key is also a `Dictionary`, but I'm getting it as `String` after conversion. I did the following steps for conversion,

```
  let hashableDictionary: [AnyHashable: Any] = [:]
  var normalDictionary: Dictionary<String, Any> = [:]
  for (key, value) in hashableDictionary {
     normalDictionary[key.description] = value
  }
```

Now, `normalDictionary` prints as above.

Note: Consider `hashableDictionary` getting from some server, which is of type `Dictionary<AnyHashable, Any>`.

I need the `payload` value as `Dictionary` instead of `String`, please help to fix this.

Comment: This looks like json, maybe you should look into json decoding using Codable.

Comment: I guess the actual response is made with the value as String. Tell your server side engineer to fix this issue.

Comment: "The problem here is, the value of payload key is also a Dictionary, but I'm getting it as String after conversion" Because that's JSON within JSON, it's JSON stringified.

Comment: @Larme, then, what should I do to get it as `Dictionary.`

Comment: @JoakimDanielson, means, I need to define and initialise a `struct` from these values to perform `Codable` operations.

Comment: @OOPer, thanks and I will check this also.